# How to update DOM element in Knockout Js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am building a custom payment method in Magento 2 where i need to show the EMI option based on card selection. I am able to render EMI option dynamically on Load but the EMI option is not getting change when i am selecting cards though i can see in console that event is getting called and its retiring the array. Here is the code i am doing.

[image]

> 1. app/code/Magento/Sanalpos/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/magento_sanalpos.js

```
 define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Pmclain_Stripe/js/action/save-payment-information',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/redirect-on-success',
        'Magento_Vault/js/view/payment/vault-enabler',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Sanalpos/js/model/form-builder',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'ko'
        //'https://js.stripe.com/v3/'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        Component,
        placeOrderAction,
        savePaymentAction,
        fullScreenLoader,
        additionalValidators,
        validator,
        redirectOnSuccessAction,
        VaultEnabler,
        quote,
        alert,
        customerData,
        url,
        formBuilder,
        priceUtils,
        ko

    ) {
        'use strict';
        var emiOption = ko.observableArray([]);
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Sanalpos/payment/form'
            },

            initialize: function() {
                this._super();
                this.getTaskit();
            },

            placeOrder: function(data, event) {

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
                var custom_controller_url = url.build('sanalpos/action/request'); //your custom controller url
                $.post(custom_controller_url, this.getData(), 'json')
                    .done(function (response) {
                        customerData.invalidate(['cart']);
                        formBuilder(response).submit(); //this function builds and submits the form
                    })
                    .fail(function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response, this.messageContainer);
                    })
                    .always(function () {
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    });
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'magento_sanalpos';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            getData: function() {
                var data = this._super();
                data.additional_data.bank_type = $('input[name="payment\\[bank_type\\]"]:checked').val();
                data.additional_data.emi       = $('input[name="payment\\[emi\\]"]:checked').val();
                data.additional_data.email     = this.getEmail();
                return data;
            },

            getEmi: function (emiCount) {
                var total = priceUtils.formatPrice(quote.totals().grand_total, quote.getPriceFormat());
                var rawTotal = parseInt(quote.totals().grand_total);
                this.emiOption = [];
                var item;
                var i;
                for (i=1; i<=emiCount; i++ ) {
                    if (i==1) {
                        item = { id:'emi'+i, title: 'Tek Ödeme, Toplam:'+ total, value: '1'};
                    } else {
                        item = { id:'emi'+i, title: i+' Taksit, Aylık Taksit: '+priceUtils.formatPrice(rawTotal/i,quote.getPriceFormat())+ ' Toplam: '+total, value: i};
                    }
                    this.emiOption.push(item);
                }
                return this.emiOption;
            },

            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            },

            getEmail: function() {
                if(quote.guestEmail) {
                    return quote.guestEmail;
                }
                return window.checkoutConfig.customerData.email;
            },

            getTaskit: function () {

                var bankType = $('input[name="payment\\[bank_type\\]"]:checked').val();
                var emiCount = window.checkoutConfig.payment['magento_sanalpos'].emiAkBank;
                this.emiOption(this.getEmi(emiCount));

                if (bankType == 'akbank') {
                    var emiCount = window.checkoutConfig.payment['magento_sanalpos'].emiAkBank;
                    this.emiOption(this.getEmi(emiCount));
                }

                if (bankType == 'isbank') {
                    var emiCount = window.checkoutConfig.payment['magento_sanalpos'].emiIsBank;
                    this.emiOption(this.getEmi(emiCount));
                }

                if (bankType == 'garantibank') {
                    var emiCount = window.checkoutConfig.payment['magento_sanalpos'].emiGarantiBank;
                    this.emiOption(this.getEmi(emiCount));
                }
                ko.applyBindings(this.emiOption);
                console.log(this.emiOption);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> 2. app/code/Magento/Sanalpos/view/frontend/web/js/template/payment/cc-form.html

```
        <fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ccard ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
        <div class="card-section col-md-6">
            <!-- ko if: (isShowLegend())-->
            <legend class="legend">
                <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Credit Card Information'--><!-- /ko --></span>
            </legend><br />
     <div class="card-option">
                <ul class="card-list">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment[bank_type]" value="garantibank" id="bonuscard" data-bind="checked: emiOption, event: { change: getTaskit}" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"/>
                        <label class="label" for="bonuscard">Bonus Card</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment[bank_type]" value="akbank" id="axesscard" data-bind="checked: emiOption, event: { change: getTaskit}" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"/>
                        <label class="label" for="axesscard">Axess Card</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment[bank_type]" value="isbank" id="maximum" data-bind="checked: emiOption, event: { change: getTaskit}" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"/>
                        <label class="label" for="maximum">Maximum Card</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment[bank_type]" value="garantibank" id="worldcard" data-bind="checked: emiOption, event: { change: getTaskit}" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"/>
                        <label class="label" for="worldcard">World Card</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
<!--------------------------- EMI Option --------------------------->
   <div class="section-emi col-md-6">
        <ul class="emi-list" data-bind="foreach: emiOption">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment[emi_type]" data-bind="attr: {id: id, value: value}" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}"/>
                <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': id}"><span data-bind="text: title"></span></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need make this variables observable not only array.

`var emi = ko.observable(0)`;

More details:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/inviqa.com/blog/using-knockout-js-magento-2%3famp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525720/knockout-not-updating-dom-when-items-changed-in-an-observable-array

Comment: Well its not working even after that also.

Comment: Did you try with numbers emi1?